# Py4JJavaError - getting error while submit PySpark job in Dataproc

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am getting error while trying to submit a PySpark job in Dataproc cluster.

gcloud submission command:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster test-cluster migrate_db_table.py
```

But getting below error:

> ('Exception occurs !!!', Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while
>   calling o31311.jdbc.\n', JavaObject id=o31313))

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Can you create a new SQLContext or HiveContext object?

Comment: Please also provide more information about your pyspark job; there isn't enough information provided to determine what's happening. How is it setting up the DB connection? Where's the DB you're connecting to? Is it inside of GCE? Is it CloudSQL? Is it remote on the external internet?

Comment: Just to know if you found the solution to your issue? It seems like a database connection issue. However, it is needed more context on what your python code performs, just like karma4917 and Dennis asked.